# Checked all Radio button then get "first td" value of their respective rows, then put on value of all first td in url right after i click submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
"my js" 
$(".hit").click(function(){    
       value = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
       location.href = "guestdetails.php?id=" + value;
    });

"my php"
foreach ($query1 as $flights) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['depart']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['arrive']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['airport']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['duration']."</td>";
                    echo "<td><label for=lbl3>  <input type='radio' checked id='lbl3' name='flight1[]' class='hit1' value='".$flights['flyonly']."'> PHP ".number_format($flights['flyonly'])."</label></td>";
                    echo "<td><label for=lbl4>  <input type='radio' checked id='lbl4' name='flight1[]' class='hit1' value='".$flights['flybaggage']."'>PHP ".number_format($flights['flybaggage'])."</label></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```

[HERE'S MY OUTPUT. I ALERT IT JUST FOR NOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vikdl.png)
The problem here is when i clicked the radio button it redirect to the guestdetails.php?id... what i need is to fill-up other radio buttons first and send all the value of first TD onto url right after i click the submit button so that i can use $_GET method to echo it out.
ADVANCE THANKS.IM BEGGINER PLS HELP.

Comment: can you show example link?

Comment: i put pic on it

Comment: line `location.href = "guestdetails.php?id=" + value; ` means you are redirecting to the location specified and passing the value with key as id. you need to get all the values before this and send after concatenating.

Comment: can u please show an example. Im super begginer in js.

Comment: We need to understand your problem first.
You will click on any of the radio button & then the js has to catch all td ids & has to be passed to the specified php file as id string ryt?
OR you need only the id of the td consisting the chosen radio button has to be passed. And all this has to happen once after clicking Next ryt? Be clear.

Comment: Ill check on any of the radio button & then the js has to catch all 'first td value' & has to be passed to the specified php file as id string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
   $(".hit").click(function(){   
  var str="";var counter=0;

  $.each($("input[name^='flight']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td:first-child"),
              function () {
   if(counter != 0 )
      str +="&";
         str +="id"+(counter+1)+"=" + $(this).text();
         counter++;
              });

 console.log(str);
 //location.href = "guestdetails.php?" + str;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr> 
<td>f</td>
<td>f</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="flight1[]"></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>f1</td>
<td>f</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="flight2[]"></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>f2</td>
<td>f</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="flight3[]"></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="hit">hit</button>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467702/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-checked-radio-button-and-the-remaining-tds-but-not

Comment: ill try it by putting :not but idk whre to put it.. Ok