# How to get the value of the checked radio button and the remaining td's but not include the radio button that has not been checked (in tr)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have here a js code to get the first value of td but what i want 
is to get the value of the checked radio button and the remaining td's value but not include the radio button that has not been checked (in tr)...............................................................................................................................

```
"my js"
     $(".hit").click(function(){   
     var str="";var counter=0;

     $.each($("input[name^='flight']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td:first-child"),
              function () {
         if(counter != 0 )
               str +="&";
               str +="id"+(counter+1)+"=" + $(this).text();
               counter++;
              });

    console.log(str);
    //location.href = "guestdetails.php?" + str;
 });

"my php"
foreach ($query1 as $flights) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['depart']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['arrive']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['airport']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$flights['duration']."</td>";
                    echo "<td><label for=lbl3>  <input type='radio' checked id='lbl3' name='flight1[]' class='hit1' value='".$flights['flyonly']."'> PHP ".number_format($flights['flyonly'])."</label></td>";
                    echo "<td><label for=lbl4>  <input type='radio' checked id='lbl4' name='flight1[]' class='hit1' value='".$flights['flybaggage']."'>PHP ".number_format($flights['flybaggage'])."</label></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the td has input type radio and it is checked then get the value else if it is not radio get the text.

```js
$(".hit").click(function(){   
var $row = $('table').find('tr:first');
var th=[];
$.each($row.find('th'),
function (index) { 
th[index]=$(this).text();
});
 var str="";var counter=0;var headCounter=th.length;
 $.each($("input[name^='flight']:checked").closest("tr").find('td'),
         function (index) {     
    if($(this).find('input:radio').length && $(this).find('input:radio').is(':checked')){
     if(counter != 0 )
    str +="&";
   str +="id"+(counter+1)+"=" +  $(this).find('input:radio').val();
   counter++;
 // adding Th here  
    str +="&";
   str +="id"+(counter+1)+"=" +  th[index%headCounter];
   counter++;
    }
    if($(this).find('input:radio').length == 0){
     if(counter != 0 )
    str +="&";
        str +="id"+(counter+1)+"=" + $(this).text();
      counter++;
      }   });
console.log(str);
//location.href = "guestdetails.php?" + str;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><th>Head3</th><th>Head4</th></tr>
  <tr> 
<td>f</td>
<td>f</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="flight1[]" value='1'></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  <td><input type="radio" name="flight1[]" value='11'></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>f1</td>
<td>f</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="flight2[]" value='12'></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
 <td><input type="radio" name="flight2[]" value='112'></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>f2</td>
<td>f</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="flight3[]" value='13'></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  <td><input type="radio" name="flight3[]" value='113'></td> <!-- FIND THIS -->
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" class="hit">hit</button>
```

Comment: bro i have output ibin.co/3EETfbS3Elku.jpg how can i stay on this current tab when the form submit? my plan is to show the result on current tab.. Im using input type submit and the result will come from db..  .. thank you.

Comment: @MistakenIdentity when you use type submit it submits the form hence refresh. use input type button and make the ajax call.

Comment: I have variable that contains ('Mark John'),('Chris Jay'),('Dan Daniels') and I have variable also that contain a value of 9.
When I insert it to database it gives me cardinality violation how to fix this?
$z = “('Mark John'),('Chris Jay'),('Dan Daniels')”;
$d = 9;
Example : Insert into passenger(User_ID,PassengerName) values ($d,($z));
The $z contains 3 names iwant also the $d to insert 3 times.How to do this? Take note im inserting multiple values ($z) in one column.